# CSS border issue with top and bottom border

Tags: css, border

I have this site here http://jamessuske.com/freelance/paoladi/ and I applied a border-top and bottom to my nav so I have two borders inbetween. But for some reason the two borders are at the top... What am I doing wrong?

```
.navigation{
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

above this class is a header class and inside the header class is a logo class and socialMedia class, one floats left and the floats right. the header class does not have a float assigned.

Comment: just give `float: left` to `.navigation` class and `clear: left` to `.contentArea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left` to the `.navigation` class

Answer (score 0):

All your li elements are floated left. You need to clear after the list.

Try adding

```
<div class="clearboth"></div>
```

after the ul

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this.

**Option 1.**

Try applying `display:inline-block` and  `width:100%;`

For Instance:

```
.navigation {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/3gJy9/)

**Option 2.**

Using a fixed `height` in pixels.

For Instance:

```
.navigation {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 65px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/3gJy9/1/)

Hope this helps.